# How to display default div when the content to be displayed is not present

Tags: php, xml

I'm new to PHP, I tried to get the data from a XML file and display it accordingly.
Now, I was successful in extracting the data and displaying it.
Below is the code -

```
if($xml_response = @simplexml_load_file('http://www.test.com/Testapp/TestSite?code=Test'))
{

            foreach ($xml_response->promotions as $promotions) {
//print_r($promotions);
                foreach ($promotions->promotion as $promotion) {
if(isset($promotion)){
                $text=$promotion->text;
                if (strlen($text) > 80) {
                                        $stringCut = substr($text, 0, 80);
                                        $text = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).' ... ';
                                        }
                ?>
<div class="ads" style="margin-right:0px;">
<a href="<?=$promotion->link;?>" title="" target="_blank">
  <h2><?php echo $promotion->title;?></h2>
  <img src="<?php echo $promotion->image;?>" align="left" width="100px" height="80px">
  <h2 style="vertical-align:text-top"><?php echo $text ?></h2></a>
  </div>

<?php }
else
{?>
<div class="ads" style="margin-right:0px;">
  <h2>Advertisement Title 1</h2>
  <img src="images/side-banner.jpg" align="left" width="100px" height="80px">
  <h2 style="vertical-align:text-top">We improve your way of working and communicating with your groups.</h2>
  </div>

<?php }           }
```

Now, I'm able to display the images when content is there but when there is no content default content should be displayed. So I checked with the `isset` condition, still I'm not able to display the default images.
Below is the XML -

```
<promotions>
<promotion>
<title>Test</title>
<text>Sign off for limited time offer</text>
<link>NewCentrescdr.jpg</link>
<image>test.jpg</image>
<date>2013-07-16</date>
</promotion>
<promotion>
<title>Test</title>
<text>Test text</text>
<link>http://www.test.com</link>
<image>test.jpg</image>
<date>2013-09-28</date>
</promotion>
</promotions>
```

Now, based on the number of promotion in XML, I want to display **`only three`** in the page. If there are no promotion, then default promotion to be displayed. In the above XML there are only 2 promotions, so the third one should be a default one.How can I do this condition

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to **simplify** it down to the bare minimum of code and get it working from there.
Once it does what you want it to do, build up from there and add HTML, CSS etc.

Code:

```
$xml_response = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

// count <promotion>, but maximum is 3
$count = count($xml_response->promotion);
if ($count > 3) $count = 3; 

// loop over <promotion>, echo it out
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$promotion = $xml_response ->promotion[$i];
    echo "$promotion->title<br />$promotion->text<br /><br />";                 
}

// if there are less than 3 <promotion>, echo out standard. 
if ($count < 3) {
    echo "Standard<br />Standard Promotion<br /><br />";
}
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/JMjPVo